# Command Inputbindings work but Shortcut does not show in MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

### Question:

I'm using Josh Smith's [implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx) of commands for MVVM using routed commands. I have a `MenuItem` binded to a command.

The input bindings are defined in the parent window. When I run the program, I **can** use the Keyboard shortcut, but the `MenuItem` does not show a `Control+O` next to the `MenuItem` header.

### Pics:

[image: Where is the Ctrl+O?]

### Code:

**Command Bindings:**

```
 <Window.CommandBindings>
    <cmd:CommandSinkBinding Command="vm:MainVM.OpenDialogCommand" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="vm:MainVM.OpenDialogCommand" Key="O" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

**Menu Item:**

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Command="vm:MainVM.OpenDialogCommand" />
```

**Note:** 
The MenuItem is styled, but removing the style does not make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Command="vm:MainVM.OpenDialogCommand" 
       InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" />
```

Comment: It works. Just curious, why does the InputGestureText appear by default for built in commands?

Comment: @Proximo because built in commands have `InputGestures` set. And by default WPF takes `DisplayString` from each `InputGesture` and displays it in the menu item as a command shortcut. For example, "Copy" command has two InputGestures. First with `DisplayString="Ctrl+Insert"`, `Key="Insert"` and `Modifiers="Control"`, and second with `DisplayString="Ctrl+C"`, `Key="C"` and `Modifiers="Control"`.